# Does CMake always evaluate install rules even for up-to-date targets?

Tags: cmake

We use CMake for both the build and install step. In case no target is out-of-date, i.e. no build steps needed to be performed, the install step still takes a considerable amount of time.

Is this normal behavior for CMake? Does CMake still evaluate an install rule for a target that was not rebuilt? Ideally, the install step should finish almost instantaneously in case no targets were out-of-date.

For completeness, an example `install()` rule in our case would be of the form:

```
add_library(foo SHARED
  ${FOO_SOURCES}
)
target_link_libraries(foo
  PUBLIC bar
)    
install(
  TARGETS foo
)
```

Instead of using `install()` rules I was thinking of adding custom commands to perform 'installation' that depend on the individual targets to ensure that no installation is done in case nothing was rebuilt. Is this a good approach?

Comment: How does the `install` target learn that nothing was rebuilt? Does it depends on the built artifacts?

Comment: @9000, I would assume so since we are using `install(TARGETS ...)` instead of `install(PROGRAMS ...)` or something similar.

Comment: What **generator** (Makefile, Visual Studio, etc.) do you use? As far as I correctly understand, in case of Makefiles `make install` is equivalent to `make all` plus **unconditional updating** installed files from the build artifacts. That it, it **always copies** the files into install tree.

Comment: Look at the target for `install`.  It looks like a custom target that executes the `install` script.  What isn't being done is creating individual rules and stamp files to only install if not already installed or target is updated. I didn't see anything in the install script that would check if something is out of date or not.  It just installs the files (and potentially update RPATH).  So I would say Yes, this is normal behavior.

Comment: I am using Ninja for the underlying build system. Looking through the install script indeed all install rules are executed unconditionally, which surprises me.